# Spring security with mongodb is not working?

Tags: spring, mongodb, security

I'm using spring security with mongodb and maven. The problem is that the login provider will not bee loaded, it doesn't go throw the provider. Spring security is not working I can get access to any pages. I have tried a lot but no any result.

Here are my codes.

```
@Component
public class LoginUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService
{

 private UserModel user;

   @Autowired
  MongoOperations op;

 public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
 {

    try
    {
        Query  query= new Query(Criteria.where("username").is(username));
        this.user = op.findOne(query, UserModel.class, "users");

        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;

        return new User(this.user.getUsername(), this.user.getPassword(), enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, getAuthorities());

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}

  public Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> getAuthorities()
  {
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities();
    for (Role role : user.getRoles())
    {
        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));
    }
    return authList;
  }

  public List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities()
  {

    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
    for (Role role : user.getRoles())
    {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));
    }

    return authorities;
  }

  }
```

mongo-database.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/mongo/mongo.properties" />

<context:annotation-config />

<mongo:db-factory dbname="${mongo.db.name}" />

<mongo:mongo host="${mongo.host.name}" port="${mongo.host.port}">

    <mongo:options connections-per-host="4" connect-timeout="1000"
        max-wait-time="1500" auto-connect-retry="true" socket-keep-alive="true"
        socket-timeout="1500" write-fsync="true" />
</mongo:mongo>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="se.company">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

spring-security.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<!-- For hashing and salting user passwords -->
<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"     class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />

<!-- Declare an authentication-manager to use a custom userDetailsService -->
 <beans:bean id="loginUserDetailsService" class="se.company.mongo.LoginUserDetailsService"/>
<authentication-manager>
<authentication-provider user-service-ref="loginUserDetailsService">
<password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
</authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/logout*" access="permitAll" />

 <intercept-url pattern="/users/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" /> 
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/users/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDenied" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/pageNotFound" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/unAuthorized" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/serverError" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/badRequest" />
    <!-- This will prevent a user from logging in multiple times - a second 
        login will cause the first to be invalidated -->
     <session-management
        session-authentication-error-url="/402">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
             error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
    </session-management>
     <session-management
        session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" />

    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/admin"
        authentication-failure-url="/error" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />

</http>

</beans:beans>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />
<!-- <bean id="loginUserDetailsService" class="se.company.mongo.LoginUserDetailsService"/> -->

<context:component-scan base-package="se.company" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/> 

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/mongo/mongo.properties" />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>

 </beans>
```

And the login page is:

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"  import="java.util.*"%>
   <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
   <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
   <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
   <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"  %>
   <%@ page import="org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder" %>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
  <head>
  <title>index</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/flexlayout/flexlayout.css" />
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <header>Date and Time: ${serverTime}</header>
 <div id='main'>
 <article>
 <h1 id="banner">Spring 3 security MongoDB Demo</h1>
 <form  action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="j_username" name="j_username" placeholder="User Name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" id="j_password" name="j_password" placeholder="Password">  </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><input value="Send" name="submit" type="submit">&nbsp;<input
                value="Reset" name="reset" type="reset"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </form>

 </article>
 <nav>nav</nav>
 <aside>aside</aside>
 </div>
<footer>footer</footer>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Please can anybody see what the problem is?
Will Bee grateful for any help. Thanks

And the web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    /web-app_2_5.xsd"
   version="2.5" metadata-complete="true">

  <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

  <!-- Spring MVC -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/mongo-database.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
 </context-param>

 <error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/views/403.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/views/404.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
    <error-code>402</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/views/402.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
 <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/views/500.jsp</location>
 </error-page>
<filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Spring Security is not intercepting any URLs at all? Have you defined the Spring Security filter in web.xml? See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-getting-started

Comment: Hi. There is no any problem with the web.xml. Have updated my post with the web.xml.
Must bee something else.

Comment: Hi
Yes you are writh the springSecurityFilterChain was missing. Mixed up with another project. Thanks a lot.